# Iteratively extract model instance's field value and default value based on field name in Django 1.6

Tags: django, django-templates, django-models

So I want to create a method in my model class (I'm using a DetailView for the view) that returns a pre-approved set of field values and user friendly names that I can call in my template. This method has to check if the field values aren't the default field values for each approved field in the model and then return a list with the field value/name pairs to my template.

**The problem is that I can't find a way of extracting `field.value()` and `field.default` as shown in my psuedocode below**:

```
def displayFields(self):
    approvedFields = [  ('field1','Field One'),
                        ('field2','Field Two'),
                        ('field3','Field Three')
                        ]
    resultFieldPairs = []
    for fieldName in approvedFields:
        field = self._meta.get_field_by_name(fieldName[0])
        if field.value() != field.default:
            resultFieldPairs.append(tuple([fieldName[1], field.value()]))
    return resultFieldPairs
```

I can see from the errors I'm getting that `self._meta.get_field_by_name()` returns a *RelatedObject*, but the Django docs don't seem to be clear on this object's attributes and methods.

Please help.

Comment: What do expect to get from `field.value()` do you mean `getattr(self, field.name)`

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't know what the actual code was :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how good it is to address the internal `_meta` attribute, normally it's not recommended, BUT - you can use

```
self._meta.get_field_by_name(fieldName[0])[0].default
```

notice the [0] because `get_field_by_name` returns a tuple in Django 1.6 with first element as the field object itself.

To get the value of this field for this instance, use:
`getattr(self, fieldName[0])`

So the code would look like:

```
for fieldName in approvedFields:
        field = getattr(self, fieldName[0])
        if field != self._meta.get_field_by_name(fieldName[0]).default:
            resultFieldPairs.append(tuple([fieldName[1], field]))
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'default'` So now we just need a way to get the default value of a field.

Comment: I'm gonna need your Model class code to understand that one. Maybe your field doesn't have a default value?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't append my code once you edited. It seems to be working now. Thanks!